# Getting header and footer hight via CSS

Tags: css, footer

Is there a way to stick the footer on a page to the bottom of the body content is shorter? I mean if the body content will be longer the footer should be displayed at the end of the whole content. The usage of the layout is not acceptable.

I tried:

```
.my-footer {
  min-height: 1vp -heightOfHeader - heightOfFooter;
 }
```

But I wish to get the values dynamically without JS. Only using CSS. Is it possible?

Comment: with only css you can't get the values dynamically. If you want a sticky footer consider to use [position: sticky](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by "The usage of the layout is not acceptable", but one way to achieve this is to use grid display.

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr auto;
}
    
.main-content {
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
}
    
footer {
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-content">Main content</div>
<footer>footer</footer>
```